# Moving a UIbutton to a random position with timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, uibutton

I am making a simple app in Objective C where every time a button is clicked, the button changes location on the screen. The first time the button is clicked, a timer begins.

The issue is every second the timer goes down, the button returns to its original position. How do I make it so that the timer does not effect the button moving?

Here is my code in my ViewController.m file:

**Note**: I cannot figure this out at all. I will probably need someone to really spell it out for me to tell me what to do. Thanks!

**Note**: My UIButton is "blackDot"

```
-(IBAction) mainClickButton{


int xmin = ([blackDot frame].size.width)/2;
int ymin = ([blackDot frame].size.height)/2;

int x = xmin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.width - blackDot.frame.size.width);
int y = ymin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.height - blackDot.frame.size.height);

[blackDot setCenter:CGPointMake(x, y)];


if (timerBeginInt < 1) {

    [timerLabel setText:@"Time : 0:10"];
    [self.view addSubview:timerLabel];
    currMinute=0;
    currSeconds=10;
    [self start];

}

timerBeginInt = timerBeginInt + 1;


}





-(void)start
{
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
-(void)timerFired
{
    if((currMinute>0 || currSeconds>=0) && currMinute>=0)
    {
        if(currSeconds==0)
        {
            currMinute-=1;
            currSeconds=59;
        }
        else if(currSeconds>0)
        {
            currSeconds-=1;
        }
        if(currMinute>-1)
            [timerLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d%@%02d",@"Time : ",currMinute,@":",currSeconds]];
    }
    else
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        timerBeginInt = 0;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: instead of setting, centre, did u try setting the frame ?

Comment: @Mr.T I haven't, how should I do that?

Comment: if u want to move a button,, simply change its frame. [button setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];

Comment: you can simply change the x and y values in there

Comment: If you are using autolayout in your storyboard, you can also directly modify the constants of the constraints if you make IBOutlets to the constraints in your class and change the values of those

Comment: @Mr.T so I tried setting the frame and did this: [blackDot setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,blackDot.frame.size.width,blackDot.frame.size.height)]; and I had the same result, every second change the dot returns its start location

Comment: @HaydenHolligan See I don't really understand constraints all to well, I am using auto layout. Is there any way you could explain in more detail what I should do? Thanks so much for the help btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LodgeApps.

i copy your code, run it with my own Xcode,and i find your problem which confuses you.

short solution is here:

open your storyboard or xib file,keep this off.
[image]

if you want to keep Autolayout on,

```
[self.view removeConstraints:blackDot.constraints];

NSLayoutConstraint* leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:blackDot attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0f constant:x];

NSLayoutConstraint* topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:blackDot attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:y];

leftConstraint.active = YES;
topConstraint.active = YES;
```

replace the `setCenter`

for deeper reason:

with autolayout property on,you can not change the frame of IBOutlet,every attempt to modify frame or center is illegal.You can only change the constraints to move the IBOutlet.

what confuses me:

According to the code,click the button,the button will move at once.but it won't.Because method like `setCenter` or `setFrame` won't work in the Autolayout.
Autolayout needs constraints to put the UI(IBOutlets) in the right place.If you keep Autolayout on,and then you do not make constraints on IBs,anything could happens which i can't explain.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this `[blackDot setCenter:CGPointMake(x, y)];`
 with this

```
[blackDot setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,blackDot.frame.size.width,blackDot.frame.size.height)];
```

Also put breakpoints and log the value of `x, y,xmin,ymin` to confirm that the new position is different than the old one.
I hope this will help you out.